# maven-build-cache ingores pom.xml changes

Tags: maven, caching

I started using [maven build cache](https://maven.apache.org/extensions/maven-build-cache-extension/). I do a [SpringBoot-Kotlin project](https://start.spring.io/) with fairly conventional file layout (sources in `/src/main/kotlin` etc.) The configuration is effective and now I often see:

```
[INFO] Skipping plugin execution (cached): surefire:test
[INFO] Skipping plugin execution (cached): jar:jar
[INFO] Skipping plugin execution (cached): install:install
[INFO] Skipping plugin execution (cached): deploy:deploy
```

as expected.

However, after editing `pom.xml` of a submodule, removing

```
-    <properties>
-        <maven.deploy.skip>true</maven.deploy.skip>
-    </properties>
```

the code was not rebuild, instead I still saw:

```
[INFO] Skipping plugin execution (cached): deploy:deploy
```

not expected.

My `maven-build-cache-config.xml` looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<cache xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/BUILD-CACHE-CONFIG/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/BUILD-CACHE-CONFIG/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/cache-config-1.0.0.xsd">
    <configuration>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <hashAlgorithm>XX</hashAlgorithm>
    </configuration>
    <input>
        <global>
            <glob>{*.java,*.kt,*.xml,*.properties,*.yml,*.yaml}</glob>
        </global>
    </input>
</cache>
```

Since `<glob>` includes `*.xml`, I expected that changes to `pom.xml` would be recognized, as stated above, this that was not the case.

What am I missing? Is there some particular heuristic of maven-build responsible for this? Do I have to declare `pom.xml` to maven-build-cache in a particular way? (And can I augment this question or rephrase its title to be more precise?)